# Creating new variable conditional on another feature using Python Parser of ArcMap Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I don't usually work in ArcGIS Desktop or Python.
I have a shapefile of road data and the roads have a 'class' feature. I want to categorize the 'Class' feature into just 5 groups and call that variable 'Type'. It's just a basic if/then but I'm screwing it up- here's an example of the data:

[image]

I looked at this [link](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm) and tried to model my code after this:

```
Parser:
Python

Expression:
Reclass(!WELL_YIELD!)

Code Block:
def Reclass(WellYield):
    if (WellYield >= 0 and WellYield <= 10):
        return 1
    elif (WellYield > 10 and WellYield <= 20):
        return 2
```

I have no idea what I'm doing and I tried this

```
def Reclass(class):
    if (class== 'motorway' OR 'primary' OR 'trunk'):
        return 'Primary'
   el if (class== 'secondary'):
        return 'Secondary'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement needed a little work. I re-wrote the first condition to a shorter equivalent of `class=='motorway' or class=='primary' or class=='trunk'`

```
def Reclass(class):
    if class in ('motorway','primary','trunk'):
        return 'Primary'
    elif class == 'secondary':
        return 'Secondary'
```